# How the Ruby equivalent of Perl Data::Dumper

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby & Perl has this very convenient module called Data::Dumper, which allows you to recursively analyze a data structure (like hash) & allow you to print it. This is very useful while debugging. Is there some thing similar for Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Look into pp

example:

```
require 'pp'
x = { :a => [1,2,3, {:foo => bar}]}
pp x
```

there is also the inspect method which also works quite nicely

```
x = { :a => [1,2,3, {:foo => bar}]}
puts x.inspect
```

Comment: Is not `p x` equivalent to `puts x.inspect`?

Comment: @Chris Yes it [is](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-p).